# Python elimination of the first words of an array problem

Tags: python

I created a little app with Python as backend and React as frontend. I receive some data from the frontend and I want to eliminate the first 20 words of the text I receive if a condition is satisfyed.

```
@app.route("/translate", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def translate():
    prompt = request.json["prompt"]

max_tokens=50

prompt = re.sub(r"^(?:.+?\b\s+?\b){20}", "", prompt)


response = translation_response(prompt)

return {'text': response}
```

How can I translate **eliminate the first 20 words** of the var prompt into python code?

Thanks a lot in advance....

Comment: what is data type of `prompt` variable?

Comment: Use `len(prompt)` instead of `prompt.length`.

Comment: It is a 'str' type but I get the following error  File "C:\Users\mario\Desktop\Vs projects\backend+frontend\volt-react-dashboard\api\demo_web_app.py", line 42, in translate
    if len(prompt > 20):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: What are the word boundaries? A single space? Any whitespace? If it's a single space and you know the prompt has more than 20 words: `" ".join(prompt.split()[20:]`. Otherwise regex might be more appropiate

Comment: @themadpsychologist `max_tokens = 50` looks like an int to me

Comment: @MarcoMarioni Could you edit your post code to reflect your current code? I'm not seeing how you could get that error.

Comment: sure. With this code I get the following error  File "C:\Users\mario\Desktop\Vs projects\backend+frontend\volt-react-dashboard\api\demo_web_app.py", line 39, in translate
    if len(prompt > 20):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

‍Consider whitespace is word delimeter:

```
my_text_as_list = my_text.split()
my_new_text = ' '.join(my_text_as_list[20:])
```

Comment: I get the following error File "C:\Users\mario\Desktop\Vs projects\backend+frontend\volt-react-dashboard\api\demo_web_app.py", line 42, in translate if len(prompt > 20): TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: try `if len(prompt) > 20:` the error is because you want to check if `prompt` is more than 20 and it is impossible @MarcoMarioni

Comment: try `if len(prompt) > 20:`  Look at the parenthesis @MarcoMarioni

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following regular expression: `^(?:.+?\b\s+?\b){20}` (explanation: https://regex101.com/r/umD2Q8/1). This will match the first twenty words, separated by any amount of whitespace and starting from the beginning of the string. The words can consist of any character except whitespace. Using python's `re.sub` will then allow you to remove the first twenty words:

```
import re

string = """one two three     four\t five six  seven eight nine ten eleven
twelve thirteen  fourteen fifteen
sixteen seventeen
eighteen nineteen twenty twentyone  twentytwo"""

string = re.sub(r"^(?:.+?\b\s+?\b){20}", "", string)
print(string)
```

This example prints `twentyone  twentytwo`. What the regex does is, starting from the start of the string (`^`), matching anything (`.+?`) until the next word boundary (`\b`), then any amount of whitespace between 1 and infinity (`\s+?`) until the start of the next word (`\b`). The `(?:...){20}` makes this repeat 20 times. If the pattern can't be matched nothing is removed. Also, regex might give you two problems instead of one so be careful.

---

Reaction to the comments:

```py
max_tokens = 50

while len(string) > max_tokens:
    match = re.match(r".+?\b\s+?\b", string)
    if match is None: break
    nextpos = match.span()[1]

    if nextpos == -1: break
    string = string[nextpos:]
    
print(string, len(string))
```

Output: `eighteen nineteen twenty twentyone  twentytwo 45`.

This will remove words until there is only one word left, or until the length of the string is less than or equal to max_tokens.

If you want to stop the word before this:

```py
while len(string) > max_tokens:
    match = re.match(r".+?\b\s+?\b", string)
    if match is None: break
    nextpos = match.span()[1]

    if len(string) - nextpos < max_token or nextpos == -1: break    
    string = string[nextpos:]
    
print(string, len(string))
```

Output: `seventeen\neighteen nineteen twenty twentyone  twentytwo 55`

If you want to cut words in half:

```py
while len(string) > max_token:
    match = re.match(r".+?\b\s+?\b", string)
    if match is None: break
    nextpos = match.span()[1]

    if nextpos == -1: break
    elif len(string) - nextpos < max_token:
        nextpos = max_token - (len(string) - nextpos)
        
    string = string[nextpos:]
    
print(string, len(string))
```

Output: `teen\neighteen nineteen twenty twentyone  twentytwo 50`

Comment: So I don't need the if len(prompt) > 20: condition?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now  I would like to have them removed not only the first 20 characters, but until len (prompt) == max_tokens. How can we do?

Comment: @MarcoMarioni This doesn't remove the first 20 chars, but the first 20 words which is what I understood you wanted from your post. If you want to remove the first `max_tokens` words, you can replace `r"^(?:.+?\b\s+?\b){20}"` with `r"^(?:.+?\b\s+?\b){" + str(max_tokens)" + "}"`

Comment: I apologize if I expressed myself wrong. I would like to remove the words present UNTIL the len (prompt) == max_tokens condition is met, and not remove a number of words equal to the value of max_tokens.

Comment: You can't be certain that that condition will ever be true, because if len(prompt) is, say, 55, and you remove a word 8 characters long, you will skip over the 50. Best you can do is put it in a while loop and run the regex without {20} bit until the length is less than max_tokens. If the regex can't match however you will be stuck in an infinite loop so you'd have to check if something is removed

Comment: SO I cannot strip until  len(prompt) == max_tokens in a while loop?

Comment: No, in most cases that would give you an infinite loop unless you get lucky with the length of the words

Comment: or maybe I can create a if elif condition like this:                                                             
 if len(prompt) < max_tokens :                                                                               
             prompt = prompt                                                                                           
  elif   len(prompt)>=max_tokens:                                                                                                                                        
             #WHILE LOOP

Comment: in this way I don't get an infinite loop.What do you think?

Comment: I don't think that would change anything if your while condition is still the == one, and prompt = prompt doesn't do anything.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant  len(prompt) >= max_tokens and NOT  len(prompt) == max_tokens

Comment: @MarcoMarioni I added three possible options for stopping before len(prompt) < max_tokens, stopping after len(prompt) < max_tokens, and making sure len(prompt) becomes equal to max_tokes

Comment: I get this error     nextpos = re.search(r"^(?:.+?\b\s+?\b)", prompt).span()[1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'

Comment: @MarcoMarioni forgot to include a check for that, edited again (and replaced search with match)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. But could you explain what do the following lines of codes mean?

Comment: match = re.match(r".+?\b\s+?\b", string)
if match is None: break
nextpos = match.span()[1

Comment: @MarcoMarioni the regex is the same as before but without repeating 20 times, and `re.match(pattern, string)` tries to match `pattern` at the beginning of `string` removing the need for `^` in the pattern. `re.match` returns a match object if the pattern matches, but `None` if it doesn't. That means that if None is returned the while loop should stop since no more words can be removed, that's what the `break` statement does. If it does match, `match.span()` returns the start and end indices. The start doesn't matter in this case, and the end can be used to slice the string

Comment: See also the documentation for [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) and [Match.span()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.span). Perhaps useful to know: if your words might contain unicode characters, you should add a unicode flag: `re.match(pattern, string, re.UNICODE)`